# How do I get array functions to work properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of id's and an array of locations that have id's and I need to return the location for each id.

```
$scope.stores = [1,22,16]

$scope.storeData = [{name:'loc1',id:1}, {name:'loc2',id:22},{name:'loc3',id:40}]
```

here is the logic I'm trying to replace

```
if(event.stores.length > 0){
  for(var i = 0; i < event.stores.length; i++ ){
     event.stores[i] = $scope.storeData.find(function(store){
                    return store.id === event.stores[i];
                })
            }
        }
```

I tried using map and filter to return a list of results, no luck so far.

Comment: why not to make a hashmap of locationInfo and then trying doing 
ids.forEach(function(id) { return locationInfo[id]; });

Comment: above is easy and is of O(n)

Comment: `locationInfo` is not mentioned in the script block.

Comment: Fixed typos, id: 40 is just the id of that location, I don't want to return it in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```js
var ids = [1,22,16]

var locationInfo = [{name:'loc1',id:1}, {name:'loc2',id:22},{name:'loc3',id:40}];

var locs = locationInfo
    .map(item=>ids.indexOf(item.id) > -1 ? item : undefined)
    .filter(e=>e);
  
console.log(locs);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgdo22tx/2/

Comment: Hey Nelson, this is very close to what I'm looking for. I need to get the whole locationInfo back.

Comment: then it's even esier. Edited the answer. See if it fits what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it

```
var map = {};
locationInfo.forEach(loc => map[loc.id] = loc.name);

var locations = ids.map(id => map[id]);
```

Of course you'll get `undefined` entries for id's that don't have a corresponding location. If necessary you can filter the locations array to remove those.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter` with `.includes` on the `stores` array and then `.map` to only return the location names.

```js
const stores = [1,22,16]

const storeData = [{name:'loc1',id:1}, {name:'loc2',id:22},{name:'loc3',id:40}]

const x = storeData.filter( item => stores.includes(item.id) ).map( item => item.name )

console.log(x)
```